# Drop javascript in html and auto-format all <code> and/or <pre> blocks

Tags: html, css, syntax-highlighting, prettify, google-code-prettify

I am looking at this google prettify project:
https://github.com/google/code-prettify

In the *usage* section it says to use it like so:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">class Voila {
public:
  // Voila
  static const string VOILA = "Voila";

  // will not interfere with embedded <a href="#voila2">tags</a>.
}</pre>
```

I am looking for a way to style all pre tags without having to add a class to the pre tag. Is there some way to do this with this library or another similar library? I am trying to syntax highlighting in the browser for Java/JavaScript etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a somewhat hacky solution, but looking at the (minified) code in that library, `prettyprint` is used in the following section:

```
u = /\bprettyprint\b/
```

and

```
if ((k !== h || u.test(n)) && !e.test(n)) {
  q = !1;
  for (l = d.parentNode; l; l = l.parentNode)
    if (w.test(l.tagName) && l.className &&
        u.test(l.className)) {
```

It tests whether the `className` of the iterated elements matches that regular expression. So, if you just remove those tests against `u`, it should work without having to add a class to the `<pre>`s:

```
if (!e.test(n)) {
  q = !1;
  for (l = d.parentNode; l; l = l.parentNode)
    if (w.test(l.tagName)) {
```

It's now only testing if `w` (`/^(?:pre|code|xmp)$/i`) matches the `tagName` of the element.

```js
!function(){/*

 Copyright (C) 2013 Google Inc.

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.

 Copyright (C) 2006 Google Inc.

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
*/
(function(){function aa(g){function r(){try{L.doScroll("left")}catch(ba){k.setTimeout(r,50);return}x("poll")}function x(r){if("readystatechange"!=r.type||"complete"==z.readyState)("load"==r.type?k:z)[B](n+r.type,x,!1),!l&&(l=!0)&&g.call(k,r.type||r)}var X=z.addEventListener,l=!1,E=!0,v=X?"addEventListener":"attachEvent",B=X?"removeEventListener":"detachEvent",n=X?"":"on";if("complete"==z.readyState)g.call(k,"lazy");else{if(z.createEventObject&&L.doScroll){try{E=!k.frameElement}catch(ba){}E&&r()}z[v](n+
"DOMContentLoaded",x,!1);z[v](n+"readystatechange",x,!1);k[v](n+"load",x,!1)}}function T(){U&&aa(function(){var g=M.length;ca(g?function(){for(var r=0;r<g;++r)(function(g){k.setTimeout(function(){k.exports[M[g]].apply(k,arguments)},0)})(r)}:void 0)})}for(var k=window,z=document,L=z.documentElement,N=z.head||z.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]||L,B="",F=z.getElementsByTagName("script"),l=F.length;0<=--l;){var O=F[l],Y=O.src.match(/^[^?#]*\/run_prettify\.js(\?[^#]*)?(?:#.*)?$/);if(Y){B=Y[1]||"";O.parentNode.removeChild(O);
break}}var U=!0,H=[],P=[],M=[];B.replace(/[?&]([^&=]+)=([^&]+)/g,function(g,r,x){x=decodeURIComponent(x);r=decodeURIComponent(r);"autorun"==r?U=!/^[0fn]/i.test(x):"lang"==r?H.push(x):"skin"==r?P.push(x):"callback"==r&&M.push(x)});l=0;for(B=H.length;l<B;++l)(function(){var g=z.createElement("script");g.onload=g.onerror=g.onreadystatechange=function(){!g||g.readyState&&!/loaded|complete/.test(g.readyState)||(g.onerror=g.onload=g.onreadystatechange=null,--S,S||k.setTimeout(T,0),g.parentNode&&g.parentNode.removeChild(g),
g=null)};g.type="text/javascript";g.src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/lang-"+encodeURIComponent(H[l])+".js";N.insertBefore(g,N.firstChild)})(H[l]);for(var S=H.length,F=[],l=0,B=P.length;l<B;++l)F.push("https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/skins/"+encodeURIComponent(P[l])+".css");F.push("https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/prettify.css");(function(g){function r(l){if(l!==x){var k=z.createElement("link");k.rel="stylesheet";k.type=
"text/css";l+1<x&&(k.error=k.onerror=function(){r(l+1)});k.href=g[l];N.appendChild(k)}}var x=g.length;r(0)})(F);var ca=function(){"undefined"!==typeof window&&(window.PR_SHOULD_USE_CONTINUATION=!0);var g;(function(){function r(a){function d(e){var a=e.charCodeAt(0);if(92!==a)return a;var c=e.charAt(1);return(a=k[c])?a:"0"<=c&&"7">=c?parseInt(e.substring(1),8):"u"===c||"x"===c?parseInt(e.substring(2),16):e.charCodeAt(1)}function f(e){if(32>e)return(16>e?"\\x0":"\\x")+e.toString(16);e=String.fromCharCode(e);
return"\\"===e||"-"===e||"]"===e||"^"===e?"\\"+e:e}function c(e){var c=e.substring(1,e.length-1).match(RegExp("\\\\u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}|\\\\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|\\\\[0-3][0-7]{0,2}|\\\\[0-7]{1,2}|\\\\[\\s\\S]|-|[^-\\\\]","g"));e=[];var a="^"===c[0],b=["["];a&&b.push("^");for(var a=a?1:0,h=c.length;a<h;++a){var m=c[a];if(/\\[bdsw]/i.test(m))b.push(m);else{var m=d(m),p;a+2<h&&"-"===c[a+1]?(p=d(c[a+2]),a+=2):p=m;e.push([m,p]);65>p||122<m||(65>p||90<m||e.push([Math.max(65,m)|32,Math.min(p,90)|32]),97>p||122<m||
e.push([Math.max(97,m)&-33,Math.min(p,122)&-33]))}}e.sort(function(e,a){return e[0]-a[0]||a[1]-e[1]});c=[];h=[];for(a=0;a<e.length;++a)m=e[a],m[0]<=h[1]+1?h[1]=Math.max(h[1],m[1]):c.push(h=m);for(a=0;a<c.length;++a)m=c[a],b.push(f(m[0])),m[1]>m[0]&&(m[1]+1>m[0]&&b.push("-"),b.push(f(m[1])));b.push("]");return b.join("")}function g(e){for(var a=e.source.match(RegExp("(?:\\[(?:[^\\x5C\\x5D]|\\\\[\\s\\S])*\\]|\\\\u[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}|\\\\x[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}|\\\\[0-9]+|\\\\[^ux0-9]|\\(\\?[:!=]|[\\(\\)\\^]|[^\\x5B\\x5C\\(\\)\\^]+)",
"g")),b=a.length,d=[],h=0,m=0;h<b;++h){var p=a[h];"("===p?++m:"\\"===p.charAt(0)&&(p=+p.substring(1))&&(p<=m?d[p]=-1:a[h]=f(p))}for(h=1;h<d.length;++h)-1===d[h]&&(d[h]=++r);for(m=h=0;h<b;++h)p=a[h],"("===p?(++m,d[m]||(a[h]="(?:")):"\\"===p.charAt(0)&&(p=+p.substring(1))&&p<=m&&(a[h]="\\"+d[p]);for(h=0;h<b;++h)"^"===a[h]&&"^"!==a[h+1]&&(a[h]="");if(e.ignoreCase&&A)for(h=0;h<b;++h)p=a[h],e=p.charAt(0),2<=p.length&&"["===e?a[h]=c(p):"\\"!==e&&(a[h]=p.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,function(a){a=a.charCodeAt(0);
return"["+String.fromCharCode(a&-33,a|32)+"]"}));return a.join("")}for(var r=0,A=!1,q=!1,I=0,b=a.length;I<b;++I){var t=a[I];if(t.ignoreCase)q=!0;else if(/[a-z]/i.test(t.source.replace(/\\u[0-9a-f]{4}|\\x[0-9a-f]{2}|\\[^ux]/gi,""))){A=!0;q=!1;break}}for(var k={b:8,t:9,n:10,v:11,f:12,r:13},u=[],I=0,b=a.length;I<b;++I){t=a[I];if(t.global||t.multiline)throw Error(""+t);u.push("(?:"+g(t)+")")}return new RegExp(u.join("|"),q?"gi":"g")}function l(a,d){function f(a){var b=a.nodeType;if(1==b){if(!c.test(a.className)){for(b=
a.firstChild;b;b=b.nextSibling)f(b);b=a.nodeName.toLowerCase();if("br"===b||"li"===b)g[q]="\n",A[q<<1]=r++,A[q++<<1|1]=a}}else if(3==b||4==b)b=a.nodeValue,b.length&&(b=d?b.replace(/\r\n?/g,"\n"):b.replace(/[ \t\r\n]+/g," "),g[q]=b,A[q<<1]=r,r+=b.length,A[q++<<1|1]=a)}var c=/(?:^|\s)nocode(?:\s|$)/,g=[],r=0,A=[],q=0;f(a);return{a:g.join("").replace(/\n$/,""),c:A}}function k(a,d,f,c,g){f&&(a={h:a,l:1,j:null,m:null,a:f,c:null,i:d,g:null},c(a),g.push.apply(g,a.g))}function z(a){for(var d=void 0,f=a.firstChild;f;f=
f.nextSibling)var c=f.nodeType,d=1===c?d?a:f:3===c?S.test(f.nodeValue)?a:d:d;return d===a?void 0:d}function E(a,d){function f(a){for(var q=a.i,r=a.h,b=[q,"pln"],t=0,A=a.a.match(g)||[],u={},e=0,l=A.length;e<l;++e){var D=A[e],w=u[D],h=void 0,m;if("string"===typeof w)m=!1;else{var p=c[D.charAt(0)];if(p)h=D.match(p[1]),w=p[0];else{for(m=0;m<n;++m)if(p=d[m],h=D.match(p[1])){w=p[0];break}h||(w="pln")}!(m=5<=w.length&&"lang-"===w.substring(0,5))||h&&"string"===typeof h[1]||(m=!1,w="src");m||(u[D]=w)}p=t;
t+=D.length;if(m){m=h[1];var C=D.indexOf(m),G=C+m.length;h[2]&&(G=D.length-h[2].length,C=G-m.length);w=w.substring(5);k(r,q+p,D.substring(0,C),f,b);k(r,q+p+C,m,F(w,m),b);k(r,q+p+G,D.substring(G),f,b)}else b.push(q+p,w)}a.g=b}var c={},g;(function(){for(var f=a.concat(d),q=[],k={},b=0,t=f.length;b<t;++b){var n=f[b],u=n[3];if(u)for(var e=u.length;0<=--e;)c[u.charAt(e)]=n;n=n[1];u=""+n;k.hasOwnProperty(u)||(q.push(n),k[u]=null)}q.push(/[\0-\uffff]/);g=r(q)})();var n=d.length;return f}function v(a){var d=
[],f=[];a.tripleQuotedStrings?d.push(["str",/^(?:\'\'\'(?:[^\'\\]|\\[\s\S]|\'{1,2}(?=[^\']))*(?:\'\'\'|$)|\"\"\"(?:[^\"\\]|\\[\s\S]|\"{1,2}(?=[^\"]))*(?:\"\"\"|$)|\'(?:[^\\\']|\\[\s\S])*(?:\'|$)|\"(?:[^\\\"]|\\[\s\S])*(?:\"|$))/,null,"'\""]):a.multiLineStrings?d.push(["str",/^(?:\'(?:[^\\\']|\\[\s\S])*(?:\'|$)|\"(?:[^\\\"]|\\[\s\S])*(?:\"|$)|\`(?:[^\\\`]|\\[\s\S])*(?:\`|$))/,null,"'\"`"]):d.push(["str",/^(?:\'(?:[^\\\'\r\n]|\\.)*(?:\'|$)|\"(?:[^\\\"\r\n]|\\.)*(?:\"|$))/,null,"\"'"]);a.verbatimStrings&&
f.push(["str",/^@\"(?:[^\"]|\"\")*(?:\"|$)/,null]);var c=a.hashComments;c&&(a.cStyleComments?(1<c?d.push(["com",/^#(?:##(?:[^#]|#(?!##))*(?:###|$)|.*)/,null,"#"]):d.push(["com",/^#(?:(?:define|e(?:l|nd)if|else|error|ifn?def|include|line|pragma|undef|warning)\b|[^\r\n]*)/,null,"#"]),f.push(["str",/^<(?:(?:(?:\.\.\/)*|\/?)(?:[\w-]+(?:\/[\w-]+)+)?[\w-]+\.h(?:h|pp|\+\+)?|[a-z]\w*)>/,null])):d.push(["com",/^#[^\r\n]*/,null,"#"]));a.cStyleComments&&(f.push(["com",/^\/\/[^\r\n]*/,null]),f.push(["com",/^\/\*[\s\S]*?(?:\*\/|$)/,
null]));if(c=a.regexLiterals){var g=(c=1<c?"":"\n\r")?".":"[\\S\\s]";f.push(["lang-regex",RegExp("^(?:^^\\.?|[+-]|[!=]=?=?|\\#|%=?|&&?=?|\\(|\\*=?|[+\\-]=|->|\\/=?|::?|<<?=?|>>?>?=?|,|;|\\?|@|\\[|~|{|\\^\\^?=?|\\|\\|?=?|break|case|continue|delete|do|else|finally|instanceof|return|throw|try|typeof)\\s*("+("/(?=[^/*"+c+"])(?:[^/\\x5B\\x5C"+c+"]|\\x5C"+g+"|\\x5B(?:[^\\x5C\\x5D"+c+"]|\\x5C"+g+")*(?:\\x5D|$))+/")+")")])}(c=a.types)&&f.push(["typ",c]);c=(""+a.keywords).replace(/^ | $/g,"");c.length&&f.push(["kwd",
new RegExp("^(?:"+c.replace(/[\s,]+/g,"|")+")\\b"),null]);d.push(["pln",/^\s+/,null," \r\n\t\u00a0"]);c="^.[^\\s\\w.$@'\"`/\\\\]*";a.regexLiterals&&(c+="(?!s*/)");f.push(["lit",/^@[a-z_$][a-z_$@0-9]*/i,null],["typ",/^(?:[@_]?[A-Z]+[a-z][A-Za-z_$@0-9]*|\w+_t\b)/,null],["pln",/^[a-z_$][a-z_$@0-9]*/i,null],["lit",/^(?:0x[a-f0-9]+|(?:\d(?:_\d+)*\d*(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d\+)(?:e[+\-]?\d+)?)[a-z]*/i,null,"0123456789"],["pln",/^\\[\s\S]?/,null],["pun",new RegExp(c),null]);return E(d,f)}function B(a,d,f){function c(a){var b=
a.nodeType;if(1==b&&!r.test(a.className))if("br"===a.nodeName.toLowerCase())g(a),a.parentNode&&a.parentNode.removeChild(a);else for(a=a.firstChild;a;a=a.nextSibling)c(a);else if((3==b||4==b)&&f){var e=a.nodeValue,d=e.match(n);d&&(b=e.substring(0,d.index),a.nodeValue=b,(e=e.substring(d.index+d[0].length))&&a.parentNode.insertBefore(q.createTextNode(e),a.nextSibling),g(a),b||a.parentNode.removeChild(a))}}function g(a){function c(a,b){var e=b?a.cloneNode(!1):a,p=a.parentNode;if(p){var p=c(p,1),d=a.nextSibling;
p.appendChild(e);for(var f=d;f;f=d)d=f.nextSibling,p.appendChild(f)}return e}for(;!a.nextSibling;)if(a=a.parentNode,!a)return;a=c(a.nextSibling,0);for(var e;(e=a.parentNode)&&1===e.nodeType;)a=e;b.push(a)}for(var r=/(?:^|\s)nocode(?:\s|$)/,n=/\r\n?|\n/,q=a.ownerDocument,k=q.createElement("li");a.firstChild;)k.appendChild(a.firstChild);for(var b=[k],t=0;t<b.length;++t)c(b[t]);d===(d|0)&&b[0].setAttribute("value",d);var l=q.createElement("ol");l.className="linenums";d=Math.max(0,d-1|0)||0;for(var t=
0,u=b.length;t<u;++t)k=b[t],k.className="L"+(t+d)%10,k.firstChild||k.appendChild(q.createTextNode("\u00a0")),l.appendChild(k);a.appendChild(l)}function n(a,d){for(var f=d.length;0<=--f;){var c=d[f];V.hasOwnProperty(c)?Q.console&&console.warn("cannot override language handler %s",c):V[c]=a}}function F(a,d){a&&V.hasOwnProperty(a)||(a=/^\s*</.test(d)?"default-markup":"default-code");return V[a]}function H(a){var d=a.j;try{var f=l(a.h,a.l),c=f.a;a.a=c;a.c=f.c;a.i=0;F(d,c)(a);var g=/\bMSIE\s(\d+)/.exec(navigator.userAgent),
g=g&&8>=+g[1],d=/\n/g,r=a.a,k=r.length,f=0,q=a.c,n=q.length,c=0,b=a.g,t=b.length,v=0;b[t]=k;var u,e;for(e=u=0;e<t;)b[e]!==b[e+2]?(b[u++]=b[e++],b[u++]=b[e++]):e+=2;t=u;for(e=u=0;e<t;){for(var x=b[e],z=b[e+1],w=e+2;w+2<=t&&b[w+1]===z;)w+=2;b[u++]=x;b[u++]=z;e=w}b.length=u;var h=a.h;a="";h&&(a=h.style.display,h.style.display="none");try{for(;c<n;){var m=q[c+2]||k,p=b[v+2]||k,w=Math.min(m,p),C=q[c+1],G;if(1!==C.nodeType&&(G=r.substring(f,w))){g&&(G=G.replace(d,"\r"));C.nodeValue=G;var Z=C.ownerDocument,
W=Z.createElement("span");W.className=b[v+1];var B=C.parentNode;B.replaceChild(W,C);W.appendChild(C);f<m&&(q[c+1]=C=Z.createTextNode(r.substring(w,m)),B.insertBefore(C,W.nextSibling))}f=w;f>=m&&(c+=2);f>=p&&(v+=2)}}finally{h&&(h.style.display=a)}}catch(y){Q.console&&console.log(y&&y.stack||y)}}var Q="undefined"!==typeof window?window:{},J=["break,continue,do,else,for,if,return,while"],K=[[J,"auto,case,char,const,default,double,enum,extern,float,goto,inline,int,long,register,restrict,short,signed,sizeof,static,struct,switch,typedef,union,unsigned,void,volatile"],
"catch,class,delete,false,import,new,operator,private,protected,public,this,throw,true,try,typeof"],R=[K,"alignas,alignof,align_union,asm,axiom,bool,concept,concept_map,const_cast,constexpr,decltype,delegate,dynamic_cast,explicit,export,friend,generic,late_check,mutable,namespace,noexcept,noreturn,nullptr,property,reinterpret_cast,static_assert,static_cast,template,typeid,typename,using,virtual,where"],L=[K,"abstract,assert,boolean,byte,extends,finally,final,implements,import,instanceof,interface,null,native,package,strictfp,super,synchronized,throws,transient"],
M=[K,"abstract,add,alias,as,ascending,async,await,base,bool,by,byte,checked,decimal,delegate,descending,dynamic,event,finally,fixed,foreach,from,get,global,group,implicit,in,interface,internal,into,is,join,let,lock,null,object,out,override,orderby,params,partial,readonly,ref,remove,sbyte,sealed,select,set,stackalloc,string,select,uint,ulong,unchecked,unsafe,ushort,value,var,virtual,where,yield"],K=[K,"abstract,async,await,constructor,debugger,enum,eval,export,from,function,get,import,implements,instanceof,interface,let,null,of,set,undefined,var,with,yield,Infinity,NaN"],
N=[J,"and,as,assert,class,def,del,elif,except,exec,finally,from,global,import,in,is,lambda,nonlocal,not,or,pass,print,raise,try,with,yield,False,True,None"],O=[J,"alias,and,begin,case,class,def,defined,elsif,end,ensure,false,in,module,next,nil,not,or,redo,rescue,retry,self,super,then,true,undef,unless,until,when,yield,BEGIN,END"],J=[J,"case,done,elif,esac,eval,fi,function,in,local,set,then,until"],P=/^(DIR|FILE|array|vector|(de|priority_)?queue|(forward_)?list|stack|(const_)?(reverse_)?iterator|(unordered_)?(multi)?(set|map)|bitset|u?(int|float)\d*)\b/,
S=/\S/,T=v({keywords:[R,M,L,K,"caller,delete,die,do,dump,elsif,eval,exit,foreach,for,goto,if,import,last,local,my,next,no,our,print,package,redo,require,sub,undef,unless,until,use,wantarray,while,BEGIN,END",N,O,J],hashComments:!0,cStyleComments:!0,multiLineStrings:!0,regexLiterals:!0}),V={};n(T,["default-code"]);n(E([],[["pln",/^[^<?]+/],["dec",/^<!\w[^>]*(?:>|$)/],["com",/^<\!--[\s\S]*?(?:-\->|$)/],["lang-",/^<\?([\s\S]+?)(?:\?>|$)/],["lang-",/^<%([\s\S]+?)(?:%>|$)/],["pun",/^(?:<[%?]|[%?]>)/],["lang-",
/^<xmp\b[^>]*>([\s\S]+?)<\/xmp\b[^>]*>/i],["lang-js",/^<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)(<\/script\b[^>]*>)/i],["lang-css",/^<style\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)(<\/style\b[^>]*>)/i],["lang-in.tag",/^(<\/?[a-z][^<>]*>)/i]]),"default-markup htm html mxml xhtml xml xsl".split(" "));n(E([["pln",/^[\s]+/,null," \t\r\n"],["atv",/^(?:\"[^\"]*\"?|\'[^\']*\'?)/,null,"\"'"]],[["tag",/^^<\/?[a-z](?:[\w.:-]*\w)?|\/?>$/i],["atn",/^(?!style[\s=]|on)[a-z](?:[\w:-]*\w)?/i],["lang-uq.val",/^=\s*([^>\'\"\s]*(?:[^>\'\"\s\/]|\/(?=\s)))/],
["pun",/^[=<>\/]+/],["lang-js",/^on\w+\s*=\s*\"([^\"]+)\"/i],["lang-js",/^on\w+\s*=\s*\'([^\']+)\'/i],["lang-js",/^on\w+\s*=\s*([^\"\'>\s]+)/i],["lang-css",/^style\s*=\s*\"([^\"]+)\"/i],["lang-css",/^style\s*=\s*\'([^\']+)\'/i],["lang-css",/^style\s*=\s*([^\"\'>\s]+)/i]]),["in.tag"]);n(E([],[["atv",/^[\s\S]+/]]),["uq.val"]);n(v({keywords:R,hashComments:!0,cStyleComments:!0,types:P}),"c cc cpp cxx cyc m".split(" "));n(v({keywords:"null,true,false"}),["json"]);n(v({keywords:M,hashComments:!0,cStyleComments:!0,
verbatimStrings:!0,types:P}),["cs"]);n(v({keywords:L,cStyleComments:!0}),["java"]);n(v({keywords:J,hashComments:!0,multiLineStrings:!0}),["bash","bsh","csh","sh"]);n(v({keywords:N,hashComments:!0,multiLineStrings:!0,tripleQuotedStrings:!0}),["cv","py","python"]);n(v({keywords:"caller,delete,die,do,dump,elsif,eval,exit,foreach,for,goto,if,import,last,local,my,next,no,our,print,package,redo,require,sub,undef,unless,until,use,wantarray,while,BEGIN,END",hashComments:!0,multiLineStrings:!0,regexLiterals:2}),
["perl","pl","pm"]);n(v({keywords:O,hashComments:!0,multiLineStrings:!0,regexLiterals:!0}),["rb","ruby"]);n(v({keywords:K,cStyleComments:!0,regexLiterals:!0}),["javascript","js","ts","typescript"]);n(v({keywords:"all,and,by,catch,class,else,extends,false,finally,for,if,in,is,isnt,loop,new,no,not,null,of,off,on,or,return,super,then,throw,true,try,unless,until,when,while,yes",hashComments:3,cStyleComments:!0,multilineStrings:!0,tripleQuotedStrings:!0,regexLiterals:!0}),["coffee"]);n(E([],[["str",/^[\s\S]+/]]),
["regex"]);var U=Q.PR={createSimpleLexer:E,registerLangHandler:n,sourceDecorator:v,PR_ATTRIB_NAME:"atn",PR_ATTRIB_VALUE:"atv",PR_COMMENT:"com",PR_DECLARATION:"dec",PR_KEYWORD:"kwd",PR_LITERAL:"lit",PR_NOCODE:"nocode",PR_PLAIN:"pln",PR_PUNCTUATION:"pun",PR_SOURCE:"src",PR_STRING:"str",PR_TAG:"tag",PR_TYPE:"typ",prettyPrintOne:function(a,d,f){f=f||!1;d=d||null;var c=document.createElement("div");c.innerHTML="<pre>"+a+"</pre>";c=c.firstChild;f&&B(c,f,!0);H({j:d,m:f,h:c,l:1,a:null,i:null,c:null,g:null});
return c.innerHTML},prettyPrint:g=function(a,d){function f(){for(var c=Q.PR_SHOULD_USE_CONTINUATION?b.now()+250:Infinity;t<r.length&&b.now()<c;t++){for(var d=r[t],k=h,n=d;n=n.previousSibling;){var q=n.nodeType,l=(7===q||8===q)&&n.nodeValue;if(l?!/^\??prettify\b/.test(l):3!==q||/\S/.test(n.nodeValue))break;if(l){k={};l.replace(/\b(\w+)=([\w:.%+-]+)/g,function(a,b,c){k[b]=c});break}}n=d.className;if(!e.test(n)){q=!1;for(l=d.parentNode;l;l=l.parentNode)if(w.test(l.tagName)){q=!0;break}if(!q){d.className+=" prettyprinted";q=k.lang;if(!q){var q=n.match(v),A;!q&&(A=z(d))&&D.test(A.tagName)&&(q=A.className.match(v));q&&(q=q[1])}if(x.test(d.tagName))l=1;else var l=d.currentStyle,y=g.defaultView,l=(l=l?l.whiteSpace:y&&y.getComputedStyle?y.getComputedStyle(d,null).getPropertyValue("white-space"):0)&&"pre"===l.substring(0,3);y=k.linenums;(y="true"===y||+y)||(y=(y=n.match(/\blinenums\b(?::(\d+))?/))?y[1]&&y[1].length?+y[1]:!0:!1);y&&B(d,y,l);H({j:q,h:d,m:y,
l:l,a:null,i:null,c:null,g:null})}}}t<r.length?Q.setTimeout(f,250):"function"===typeof a&&a()}for(var c=d||document.body,g=c.ownerDocument||document,c=[c.getElementsByTagName("pre"),c.getElementsByTagName("code"),c.getElementsByTagName("xmp")],r=[],k=0;k<c.length;++k)for(var n=0,l=c[k].length;n<l;++n)r.push(c[k][n]);var c=null,b=Date;b.now||(b={now:function(){return+new Date}});var t=0,v=/\blang(?:uage)?-([\w.]+)(?!\S)/,u=/\bprettyprint\b/,e=/\bprettyprinted\b/,x=/pre|xmp/i,D=/^code$/i,w=/^(?:pre|code|xmp)$/i,
h={};f()}},R=Q.define;"function"===typeof R&&R.amd&&R("google-code-prettify",[],function(){return U})})();return g}();S||k.setTimeout(T,0)})();}()
```

```html
<pre>class Voila {
public:
  // Voila
  static const string VOILA = "Voila";

  // will not interfere with embedded <a href="#voila2">tags</a>.
}</pre>
```